# Pop last command from comint-input-history

Tags: emacs, elisp, comint-mode

How to programmatically pop the last command from `comint-input-history`?

I tried something like `(pop (cdr (cdr comint-input-ring)))` but that does not work.

It seems to be an array, but I'm also stuck with `(aref (cdr (cdr comint-input-ring)) 0)`

Answer (score 0):

The `comint-input-ring` is a [ring](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Rings.html), and as such should be manipulated with ring functions.  And, I'm not sure if you mean "last" as in the most recent (the "last" thing I typed) or "last" as in oldest.

If you want to remove the oldest ([FIFO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFO_%28computing_and_electronics%29)), you can do:

```
(ring-remove comint-input-ring)
```

If you want to remove the most recent ([LIFO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_%28abstract_data_type%29)), you can do:

```
(ring-remove comint-input-ring (ring-size comint-input-ring))
```